# What is the country code of South Africa- ZAF error

Tags: magento-1.9

There is error when i try to enter south Africa country code, am googled south Africa country code zaf, but not support in Shipping matrixrate.[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you only have ZAF in that column? Looks like there's another Unicode character in there.

Comment: did you see my excel sheet screen shot

Comment: I did. It's possible that there is a non-rendering character in there. If you typed it by hand, then no problem. Also, I think you are using a third party table rate extension. Which one?

Comment: webshops matrix rate.

Comment: Questions about third-party modules are often considered to be off-topic, but as this is a widely-used extensions *and* you are asking about userland functionality, I'm inclined to leave this open.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked my shop and I am using Country Code 'ZA' for South Africa. Give it a go.

Comment: make sure you are using 2 letter country (ZA) code or three letter (ZAF) country code ??